# Convert "Friday, February 1, 2013" to "2013-02-01"

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

How can I perform this conversion in Java?

Currently, I'm doing:

```
public static String formatDate(String strDateToFormat) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM DD, YYYY");
        Date date = sdfSource.parse(strDateToFormat);
        SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return sdfDestination.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        System.err.println("Parse Exception : " + pe);
    }

    return null;
}
```

However, this results in an incorrect format. It gives me the following output:

```
Friday, February 1, 2013 > 2013-01-04
Thursday, January 31, 2013 > 2013-01-03
```

Comment: Why have you repeated the output for two values so many times?

Comment: Change "DD" by "d" and "YYYY" by "yyyy"

Comment: I would replace `System.err.println("Parse Exception : " + pe);` with `pe.printStackTrace();`. Or, better yet, throw that exception from your method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using `DD` in your parsing part, which is the day of year. You want `dd` instead. You also probably want `yyyy` (year) instead of `YYYY` (week year). (In most cases they're the same value, but not always.)

Answer (score 3):

You're using DD in your parsing part, which is the day of year. You want dd instead.
Change also YYYY in yyyy.

You can find all patterns here.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

Your code has got ***two major problems*** and the existing answers have already solved one of them. The second and ***even more dangerous*** problem is, not using `Locale` with `SimpleDateFormat`, which is a `Locale`-sensitive type. Since your Date-Time string is in English, make sure to use `Locale.ENGLISH` or some other English-`Locale`. So, a correct initialization would be:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, y", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Check [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573) to learn more about it. Also, notice a single `d` which, for parsing, can cater to both single-digit as well as double-digit representation of a day-of-month. Similarly, a single `y` can cater to both two-digit as well as four-digit representation of a year.

### Switch to the modern Date-Time API

Note that the `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> released with Java SE 8 in March 2014.

### Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Friday, February 1, 2013";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, MMMM d, u", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(input, dtf);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2013-02-01
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/1gVJPq)

**Some notes:**

1. Here, you can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer `u` to `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573).
2. The [`LocalDate#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--) gives you a `String` in [ISO-8601 format] which is the exact same format you are expecting. So, you do not need to format `LocalDate` explicitly to obtain a `String` in this format.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>